# Printing out a list of unknown size in a function in python

Tags: python

I have a function that takes in a list of class instances (but sometimes it could just be a single no list class instance) and I want to print it out regardless if it is a list or not.  I know you can do it by doing something like this:

```
def func(obj):
    if type(obj) == list:
        for o in obj:
            print o
    else:
    print obj
```

Is there a fast, better way to do this or is this the cleanest way?

Comment: why not just `print obj`

Comment: I want to get each object and then do other processing on them, I just put print as an easy example, I can add more of what I mean to do if need be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial thought using simplest python code would be:

```
def func(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj,list):
        obj = [obj]
    for o in obj:
        print o
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(obj):
    return map(some_function,obj) if isinstance(obj,(list,tuple)) else some_function(obj)
```

maybe?  for some definition of better

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to feed it just a single class instance, why not make it into a single item list to make everything easier? That way you can always deal with the input as a list

```
def func(obj):
    for o in obj:
        print o

func([single_class])
func([class_one, class_two, class_n])
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this??

```
def func(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, list):
        obj = [obj]
    map(f, obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well...

```
def func(*obj):
    print(*obj)
```